# Put a fixed text inside a image - responsive with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to put text and a button inside an image, but I can't keep them responsive.

```css
.dados {
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 0;
}

.text {
    font-family: "Arial Bold", Arial;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <title>Teste</title>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row mt-4">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="position-relative">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="">
          <div class="position-absolute dados">
            <h3 class="text-right text">Testes?<br>Teste teste teste teste</h3>
            <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">veja detalhes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="position-relative">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="">
          <div class="position-absolute dados">
            <h3 class="text-right text">Testes?<br>Teste teste teste teste</h3>
            <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">veja detalhes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="position-relative">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="">
          <div class="position-absolute dados">
            <h3 class="text-right text">Testes?<br>Teste teste teste teste</h3>
            <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">veja detalhes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I tried to set the parent div to position relative, and tried to hit the information with position absolute, but it didn't work.

I want this information to be inside the image in the lower right corner. Does anyone know how to do this so that they remain responsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap Cards and image overlay.
For more reference refer https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_cards.asp
and https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/
Try the snippet in full page to see responsiveness

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/300.png" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some example text . Some example text some example text. </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card ">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/300.png" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some example text . Some example text some example text. </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card img-fluid">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/300.png" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some example text. Some example text some example text. </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Update :** You can use flex to achieve the same

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

card-img-overlay {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/300.png" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
      <div class="card-img-overlay card-body d-flex flex-column" style="">
       <div class="mt-auto">
       <h4 class="card-title ">John Doe</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some example text. Some example text some example text. </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/300.png" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
      <div class="card-img-overlay card-body d-flex flex-column" style="">
       <div class="mt-auto">
       <h4 class="card-title ">John Doe</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some example text. Some example text some example text. </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/300.png" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
      <div class="card-img-overlay card-body d-flex flex-column" style="">
       <div class="mt-auto">
       <h4 class="card-title ">John Doe</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some example text. Some example text some example text. </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

See it in full screen to see that button and everything have moved to bottom.
If you want anything at top , move it outside of `<div class="mt-auto">`.

Comment: How to throw the items to the bottom? With positions the same way I was doing?

Answer (score 0):

added

```
img {
  min-height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%

}
```

to `img`

```css
.dados {
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 0;
}

.text {
  font-family: "Arial Bold", Arial;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

img {
  min-height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <title>Teste</title>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-4">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="position-relative">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="">
          <div class="position-absolute dados">
            <h3 class="text-right text">Testes?<br>Teste teste teste teste</h3>
            <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">veja detalhes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="position-relative">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="">
          <div class="position-absolute dados">
            <h3 class="text-right text">Testes?<br>Teste teste teste teste</h3>
            <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">veja detalhes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="position-relative">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="">
          <div class="position-absolute dados">
            <h3 class="text-right text">Testes?<br>Teste teste teste teste</h3>
            <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">veja detalhes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Julio check now

Answer (score 0):

make your relative box padding top `100%` and you image should also in `absolute` position and also apply css to image as I apply applied so now if you are use any size of image the is set the you image inside the box without starch or squeeze and display center square portion of the image.

see my snippet for solution.

```css
.position-relative img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.position-relative {
  padding-top: 100%;
}
.position-absolute {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <title>Teste</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-4">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-3">
        <div class="position-relative">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="">
          <div class="position-absolute dados">
            <h3 class="text-right text">Testes?<br>Teste teste teste teste</h3>
            <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">veja detalhes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-3">
        <div class="position-relative">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="">
          <div class="position-absolute dados">
            <h3 class="text-right text">Testes?<br>Teste teste teste teste</h3>
            <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">veja detalhes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-3">
        <div class="position-relative">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="">
          <div class="position-absolute dados">
            <h3 class="text-right text">Testes?<br>Teste teste teste teste</h3>
            <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">veja detalhes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```